# Preventing default on contextmenu event triggers subsequent click event

Tags: javascript, safari, event-handling, dom-events

Okay, here's some bizarre Safari behavior.

**Summary:**

Suppose I want to disable the context menu on my webpage.  However, when the user right-clicks on the blue square, I want to run `openSpecialMenu()`.  In order to match this desired behavior, I have:

1. An `contextmenu` event listener on the document that calls `event.preventDefault()`.  This prevents the context menu from appearing.
2. An `contextmenu` event listener on the blue square that calls `openSpecialMenu()`.

Now, suppose my special menu closes itself on `click` events, as most popup menus do.

I re-created this scenario in the following snippet:

```js
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('document contextmenu prevented');
});

document.getElementById("thing").addEventListener('contextmenu', function(event) {
  console.log('blue square contextmenu');
  
  // This opens my special menu.
  // openSpecialMenu();
});

document.getElementById("thing").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  console.log('blue square click');
  
  // My special menu closes if this is run.
});

document.getElementById("thing").addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
  console.log('blue square mouseup');
  
  // My special menu closes if this is run.
});
```

```css
#thing {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="thing"></div>
```

Take a look on Safari.  Using CTRL + click, "right-click" on the blue square in the Codepen output with the console open.  Notice that events are fired in the following order:

```
blue square contextmenu
document contextmenu prevented
blue square click
```

This mostly looks okay... except for this `blue square click` event.  You might be wondering why a `click` event is being fired on Safari when CTRL is being held... shouldn't the `contextmenu` event eat that?

Now comment out the `event.preventDefault()` and try again.  Notice that this time, the `blue square click` console log doesn't appear.  What's happening?

**My dumb, intuitive theory:**

Preventing the `contextmenu` event with `preventDefault` causes Safari to treat the event as a `click` event.  AFAIK, this is behavior only with Safari, have not been able to repro on Chrome, Edge, FF.

**Why is this a problem?**

If `click` events are being fired here, then my special menu is closed *immediately after it is opened*.  My function `openSpecialMenu()` is correctly called, but then a `click` event is triggered immediately after, and the special menu closes again.

**My questions:**

1. Is this a known bug with Safari?  Is this even a bug?
2. How can I work around this?  I can write some hacky solution where I check the browser and check to see if `click` events are fired quickly after `contextmenu` events... but I'm looking for something more robust.